# How to get every value in template which use each

Tags: templates, meteor, each

```
<template name="mytemplate">
    {{#each work}}
        <div name="adiv">
            <input type='hidden' value={{_id}} id="testid"> <br/> 
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

If I use document.getElementById('testid'),It just get the lasted value.But I want to get the every value.

Comment: Usually `id` should be unique in your HTML/DOM tree. I'd use `class="testclass"` instead to keep `id` for unique elements only. Then you can use `template.$('.testclass')` inside the template helper. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$

Answer (score 1):

It's because id value is meant to be unique,
change id to class and `document.getElementByClassName('testid')` will return an array